# How to output a variable with Stylus syntax

Tags: css, stylus

If I have a few variables in stylus like this:

```
emphasisBackground = emphasis(0%, emphasisTop, emphasisBottom)
emphasisHover = emphasis(20%, emphasisTop, emphasisBottom)
emphasisActive = emphasis(-10%, emphasisTop, emphasisBottom)
```

emphasis is my own mixin that returns some properties like background, filter (for IE), etc.
how can I display those variables?

```
a
  emphasisBackground
```

this doesn't work, Stylus thinks it's a property, not a variable

```
a unquote(s('%s',emphasisBackground))
```

this doesn't work either, it just prints the filter property for IE, but not all of the lines of the variable

Do I have to turn those things into mixins?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get that effect would be to nest mixins

```
// Mixin that does the work (whatever that is) 
emphasis(percent, eStart, eStop)
  .
  .
  .

// Helper mixins 
emphasisBackground 
  emphasis(0%, emphasisTop, emphasisBottom)

emphasisHover 
  emphasis(20%, emphasisTop, emphasisBottom)

emphasisActive 
  emphasis(-10%, emphasisTop, emphasisBottom)
```

Then use it just like you are now.

```
a
  emphasisHover
```

If that's not acceptable you can add a bit more detail about what you are doing and I will see if I can assist you.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. It just makes me feel like stylus doesn't have great support for control of evaluation. While I can assign things to variables, there is no way to print them out unless they're mixins.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to interpolate variables into the result of a parameterize mixin. That would be a cool shorthand though. Not what you want but a bit more compact would be to do a single line      emphasisActive() { emphais(0%,emphasisTop,emphasisBottom) }

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release of Stylus there is `@block` support ([docs](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/block.html)).

With it you can make any function return a `block` object that you could save into the variable and then use anywhere you'd like, an abstract example:

```
foo(w, h)
  return @block {
    width: w
    height: h
  }

bar = foo(10px, 20px)
baz = foo(20px, 30px)

a
  {bar}

b
  {baz}
```

would render to

```
a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}
b {
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
}
```